# tikz: removing borders in fill white

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, fill

This is what I got with the following  code
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[blue!20] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4);
\fill[white] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I wonder how to remove borders in fill. Thanks

**Edited**

Using the solution given by @Ulrike Fischer, I get something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[blue!20] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4) -- cycle;
\fill[white, draw = white, thick] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) --cycle; 

\fill[green!20] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) -- cycle ;
\fill[white, draw = white, thick] (90:4) -- (155:2) -- (25:2) -- cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This appends extra space between two pieces.

Comment: Have you tried `draw=none`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `draw = none` but without any success. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, you don't have borders. The the *border effect* is generated because the blue triangle is drawn first then the white triangle (which has smaller dimensions) is drawn on top of it, hence a border is generated. You can achieve your desired output by slightly changing your coordinates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue!20] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4);
    \fill[white] (90:4.5) -- (190:2.615) -- (-10:2.615) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Now for @Ulrike Fischer answer, though it is good and unique, the same problem occurs. The solution requires to draw 4 distinct shapes (one is overdrawn by two triangles which is giving resulting in that *border effect*). Try to comment `\fill[white, draw = white, thick] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) --cycle;` and change your colors to solid blue, red and black (for better visualization) and you will see a better result, but the problem persists at a lower significance.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to draw the smaller triangle explicitly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[blue!20] (90:4) -- (210:4) -- (-30:4) -- cycle;
\fill[white,draw=white,thick] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) --cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike for useful answer. Now if I add 
`\fill[green!20] (90:4) -- (190:2.6) -- (-10:2.6) -- cycle ;
\fill[white, draw = white, thick] (90:4) -- (155:2) -- (25:2) -- cycle;`, then I get extra space between two pieces. Any thoughts.

Comment: Then I would start to consider not to do the drawing by superimposing triangles. This pixel artefact are hard to come by.